# How to use function inside component that return string on react/next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, netlify, react-functional-component

Below code works well when I test on local environment. But when I am going to build on netlify, it shows error.

```
const Fundraiser = (props) => {
    const truncate = ( str, n, useWordBoundary ) => {
        if (str.length <= n) { return str; }
        const subString = str.substr(0, n-1);
        return ((useWordBoundary?subString.substr(0, subString.lastIndexOf(" ")):subString) + "...");
    }
    return (
        ...
        <p className="m-b-0 font-14">{props.buttonShow?truncate(props.description, 350, true):props.description}</p>
        ...
    )

}
export default Fundraiser;
```

-netlify build log

```
7:41:48 AM:     at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
7:41:48 AM:     at Object.renderToString (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
7:41:48 AM:     at Object.renderPage (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:596:45)
7:41:48 AM:     at Function.getInitialProps (/opt/build/repo/.next/server/pages/_document.js:601:19)
7:41:48 AM:     at Object.loadGetInitialProps (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/utils.js:69:29)
7:41:48 AM: info  - Generating static pages (13/13)
7:41:48 AM: > Build error occurred
7:41:48 AM: Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
7:41:48 AM:     /explorer
7:41:48 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:487:19
7:41:48 AM:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
7:41:48 AM:     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
7:41:48 AM:     at async /opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:833:17
7:41:48 AM:     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
7:41:48 AM:     at async /opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:707:13
7:41:48 AM:     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
7:41:48 AM:     at async Object.build [as default] (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:77:25)
7:41:48 AM: error Command failed with exit code 1. (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
7:41:48 AM: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
7:41:48 AM: ​
7:41:48 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:41:48 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
7:41:48 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:41:48 AM: ​
7:41:48 AM:   Error message
7:41:48 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: yarn build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
7:41:48 AM: ​
7:41:48 AM:   Error location
7:41:48 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
7:41:48 AM:   yarn build
7:41:48 AM: ​
```

I newly defined truncate function to cut off the string. The script works well if I don't use truncate function on local and netlify as well. That tells the truncate function has a problem. Could you tell me what is wrong on my code?

Comment: Where in the error logs do you see the problem being with the truncate function?

Comment: I can't see error through the log. but I am sure the issue is on calling truncate function.

Comment: So if you removed/commented the truncate function and deployed, it builds successfully?

Comment: I solved the problem myself. The issue was when the description string can't be operatable by truncate function while it has not defined(the length is not defined). Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JamesLiu You may want to add the solution that worked for you as an answer to your own question.